# Using GruntJS to delete old files

Tags: gruntjs

Hello people of the world. I've been trying to automate my grunt workspace for a static web app. An example of my file structure is below. My current grunt setup watches for changes in files in the src folder, and if there is a change, it processes and updates only the files that have changed using grunt-newer, and puts them in the minified folder.

Let's say that I delete styles.scss from the src folder. Then I also need the corresponding styles.css to get deleted. Is there any way that I can automate this with Grunt? As shown in the problem above, I also need it to know that styles.css in the minified folder corresponds to styles.scss in the src folder.

File structure:

- src

  - styles.scss
  - index.haml
- minified

  - styles.css
  - file.html

Edit: Something like this: https://github.com/tschaub/grunt-newer/issues/15
Note that there is no solution to that issue

Comment: I think you should do a "clean" task remove your minifed files and when you delete your "styles.scss" you run "clean" task manually and then you regenerate all others minified files.

Comment: I was hoping to automate this. Great idea though...

Comment: I construct an answer with my proposition :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this on your GruntFile:

```
sass: {
    dist: {
        files: {
            'style/style.css' : 'sass/style.scss'
        }
    }
},
watch: {
    css: {
        files: '**/*.scss',
        tasks: ['clean','sass'],
        options: {
          event: ['deleted'],
        },
    }
},
clean: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      src: [
        'dist/*.css'
      ]
    }]
  }
}
```

As it, if you delete (and only deleted) a .saas file, your dist folder will be automaticly cleaned and your sass file rebuild.

It use:

- grunt watch: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch
- grunt saas: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass
- grunt clean: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean

A nice tutorial: http://ryanchristiani.com/getting-started-with-grunt-and-sass/

Hope this help!

Comment: Is here a possibility that I can access the file that was deleted from the watch task? That would allow for multiple scss files. Great answer. I just need to solve the above problem for things like haml and coffeescript, which don't have something like import. And also, I'm using grunt newer to only process files that have changed, and delete everything for one deleted file would defeat the purpose.

Comment: There is! search "grunt.event.on" on https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch and you will have all what you need (a bit long to copied here). For other kind of file, you can process other task if there is a plugin available for them.

Comment: Thanks you very much!